# Rigid-body Rotation and Kinetic

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotation, rotational-kinematics

Math and formula issue

1. Default Kinetic energy formula
2. [image]
3. [image]

My question is

- How did we go from 2 to 3 ?

**I do not understand where the: (V_cm/R^2) comes from. Please give a description, where do i fail.**

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie Ok. I have to rephrase my question i guess, since there is something i do not understand. Do i need to edit existing post or create a new post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$E_{rotation} = \frac 12 I \omega ^2$$ is the equation you started with.

For a hoop, we know $$I = MR^2$$ and for rotation we know that angular velocity ($\omega$) can be related to linear velocity at a point in the rotation by the relation $$\omega = \frac vR$$  If the centre of mass is moving at $v_{cm}$ and the hoop is not slipping, we can find the rolling velocity through this equation. That is because where the hoop touches the ground relative velocity is 0, and we know the velocity at the centre, a distance R away from where we have no rotation, so we can relate $\omega$ to $\frac{v_{cm}}{R}$ knowing that.

Substituting that in we get $$E_{rotation} = \frac 12 (MR^2)(\frac vR)^2= \frac 12 MR^2 \frac{v^2}{R^2}$$ Which is what the answer shows.

Comment: I know get the problem over here! Thanks for help  on this!